# Uploading a File with servlets?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a problem with my web application, I'm trying to upload a file but the console show me some errors. I'm using the Apache Commons Fileupload API.

This is my **Servlet** `CargaArchivo.java`:

```
File repository = new File(this.getServletContext().getRealPath("repository"));//Create a new DIR to the files
        repository.mkdir();//Make it DIR
        System.out.println("================Path: " + repository.getAbsolutePath());//Show the PATH of the DIR
        factory.setRepository(repository);//Here is the problem
```

Of course the **form**(just in case) `index.html`:

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="CargaArchivo">
            <label for="archivo">Archivo:</label>
            <input type="file" id="archivo" name="inputFile">

            <button>Cargar</button>
        </form>
```

And this the **output** `console`:

```
Información:   ================Path: C:\Users\lopez-e\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Tutorial_CargaArchivo\build\web\repository
Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[CargaArchivo]: Servlet.service() for servlet CargaArchivo threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils
```

I do not know what's wrong.

Comment: Deploy `org.apache.commons.io.jar` with your web app

Comment: You lack libraries to do the job. Add Apache Commons IO to your WEB-INF/lib or as dependency in your dependency manager tool (maven, gradle or whatever you use), recompile and redeploy the project.

Comment: I thought the Apache API that library already had implemented.Thanks friend